# BatchApexClass must implement the method: System.Iterator<SObject>?

Tags: apex, batchapexerrorevent

Why am i getting this error? I'm just converting my csv file and giving it as an input to execute. I think i should not use QueryLocatorIterator at start here but i don't know what to replace.

> Class BatchApexClass must implement the method: System.Iterator System.Iterable.iterator()

```
global class BatchApexClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{

    global Integer count = 0;
    public Blob csvBody;
    public string csvString;
    public String[] csvLines;
    public List<Transaction__c> transactionList;

    public PermissionSetApexClass() {
        csvLines = new String[]{};
        transactionList = New List<Transaction__c>();
    }

    global Database.QueryLocatorIterator.start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        transactionList.clear();
        csvString = csvBody.toString();
        csvLines = csvString.split('\n');

        for(Integer i=0 ; i < csvLines.size() ; i++) {
            count =+ 1;
            string[] csvRecordData = csvLines[i].trim().split(',');
            transactionList.add( new Transaction__c(
            Customer__c = Id.valueof( csvRecordData[0].trim()),
            CustomerName__c = csvRecordData[1].trim(),
            Action__c = csvRecordData[2].trim(),
            Amount__c = Double.valueof(csvRecordData[3].trim())
            ));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have a number of issues here:

1. you have "Database.QuerylocatorIterator.start" - start is the method name, not part of the return type name and you either return a Database.QueryLocator OR an Iterator<SObject>
2. your "start" method needs to return a query locator OR iterable - I suspect the latter is what you need given you want to process data from a blob rather than obtained via an SOQL query
3. you don't have the "execute" and "finish" methods

I suggest you read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) for further guidance.

Note that your blob is part of your batchables initialization state and will therefore need to be persisted to the database during the Database.executeBatch(...) call. This may cause you issues depending on how big this data is. I'm not even sure this would work. Personally, I would consider converting the blob to the SObject instances you want in the constructor, rather than the start method. That said, you will still be asking the Salesforce platform to persist a lot of state data in your batch and this could cause you problems.

Comment: I have edited the question now @PHIL ....Thank u for your response.Please help me one more time with error " Unknown property 'BatchApexClass.csvString' " in my VF Page.I have no Idea .. As of now cleared the errors in Batch Apex class by ur guidance..Help would be greatly appreciable.Thanks

Comment: I am NEW to batch apex class concept ...

Comment: Hi Lokesh, you updated the question so none of the points I responded to are there any more. This means others won't benefit from the question and answer in the future. My recommendation would have been to raise a new question for the new issue.

Comment: You need a controller for your visualforce page that exposes the required properties, such as csvString and csvBody. Your controller can then pass those values through to a batch instance when you need to execute it. You should not use the batch as your controller - they have utterly different roles and responsibilities. Additionally, properties exposed on the controller must be public to make them accessible in the page but the properties on the batch should be private since they are for internal state in the batch.

Comment: I've rolled back these changes to ensure that Phil W.'s answer remains meaningful. Please open a new post for any follow-up questions, but make sure to read the relevant documentation and attempt to debug your code first.

Comment: Sure @David . Thanks @ Phil W but rather than having a Vf page, i used another technique i.e., Documents in Salesforce to where i uploaded the csv file and fetched it in the batch class using the query [Select body from Document where Name = 'My file name']. **THANKS**